# Hidden new line characters in string?

Tags: string, powershell, newline

I have this response coming back from an API, which appears to have newline characters in it. But, I cannot find what characters are actually there, and thus cannot split this string.

```
$response = curl.exe POST --silent --user $creds --data-raw $request $url
$response.contains("`f")
$response.contains("`r")
$response.contains("`n")
$response
```

Output:

```
False
False
False
"92837F755","BES","780532219"
"46431P106","BES","!NA"
"Y2069P309","BES","!NA"
```

Comment: Try `$Reponse.Trim()` this will remove any whitespace/etc at the beginning and end of lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$response` contains an array of strings. Echoing the array displays one string at a time, even though the individual strings don't contain any of the characters you're testing for.

If you want the response as a single string without newlines you can simply put the variable in double quotes:

```
"$response"
```

By default this joins the array elements with a space between them. If you don't want that you can set `$OFS = ''` first, or simply join the array with an empty string:

```
$response -join ''
```

or

```
-join $response
```

If you want the response with newlines you can pipe the `curl` output through `Out-String`:

```
$response = curl.exe ... | Out-String
```

Comment: A quick check you could have done was `$Response.GetType()`, and it would have shown that you have an array instead of a string.